# how to pass char pointer to function and return another string in ( C )?

Tags: function-pointers

i have a code to find table name in SQL query . i create function to check char pointer and i need return table name string .

my function

```
  char* SQLParser_GetTable(char *query)
 {
   const char *str = "my string";

return *str;
 }
void PrintRows(char *TableName)
 {

 }
 void doSELECT(char *query)
 {
   printf("do SELECT :");
   PrintRows(SQLParser_GetTable(*query));   
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const char* SQLParser_GetTable(char *query)
{
  const char *str = "my string";
  return str;
}
```